# Best way to allow users to upload and download files across multiple platforms?

Tags: file-upload, download

I'm working on a project where I need to allow users to upload files from desktops (Python based app), mobile phones (PhoneGap/Cardova) and a web interface (PHP). What should I use for this ? FTP or HTTP(using PHP POST form perhaps ?) or something else entirely ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a universal way to consume a POST request. Typically for this people today will build a RESTful API backend. Especially since your looking to use your service from multiple system types/devices. JSON is a very easy format to deal with as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTP with an HTML POST form that will send the file to a Python CGI script. You can use Python as a common gateway interface language. **(It is like using Python instead of PHP for some things)**

Create an "uploads" folder in your main website directory and put the code below into a "cgi-bin" folder as "save_file.py". Then you can use the HTML form below on a webpage to upload a file. The name of the field should be "file". To make this work, an actual server needs to be running. It won't work if you open the html page as a "file://..." on your computer. Also, you will have to enable CGI on your server to make this work.

HTML Form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../cgi-bin/save_file.py" method="post">
<input type="file" name="file" required>
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Python Script to receive files. Save it as "safe_file.py" and put into the cgi-bin folder. If it receives some input from the "POST" form above, it will upload the file into the "uploads" folder created earlier. You may have to do some more editing to this script so it doesn't overwrite the files if they have a same name.

```
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable() #Good debugging module

try: #Adds some useful capabilities on Windows Platform
    import msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode (0, os.O_BINARY) # stdin  = 0
    msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY) # stdout = 1
except ImportError:
    pass

form = cgi.FieldStorage() #Receiving the file from POST form

fileitem = form['file'] #Reading the file
description = ""
if form.getvalue('textcontent'):
    description = form.getvalue('textcontent')

if fileitem.filename:
    fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
    f = open('uploads/' + fn, 'wb') #Putting the file into uploads folder
    f.write(fileitem.file.read())
    f.close()
    message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'

else:
    message = 'No file was uploaded'

print """\
Content-Type: text/html\n
<html><body>
<p>%s</p>
</body></html>
""" % (message)
```

Comment: So on the desktop and mobile apps etc I would upload a file by doing a POST method right ? And is there any security concerns I should watch out for in this method ?

Comment: And are there any advantages of using a CGI script rather than a PHP script to handle the uploaded file ?

Comment: @GrimReaper, it is not quite possible to use GET method for uploading files as the input is encoded in the URL and in most cases cannot be longer than 2028 characters. In addition, I do not think there is a difference between CGI and PHP as far as file uploads go. I used Python in the answer just because I am a lot more familiar with it and it proved to work. [This website compares the GET and POST methods](http://www.diffen.com/difference/GET_(HTTP)_vs_POST_(HTTP)